# Hiding a php GET using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rather strange .htaccess question. I am building a multi lingual website and need to virtually hide a page.php?lang=en page ending.

I know that I can change `www.domain.com/page.php?lang=eng` to `www.domain.com/page/eng` but is it possible to show the domain as `www.domain.com/eng/page`.

Any .htaccess guides would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes it is possible and not that different from the first rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this: `www.domain.com/eng/page`, you'd need to put something like this in the htaccess file in your **document root**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+page\.php\?lang=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/page? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/page$ /page.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank-you very much! I will accept your answer shortly @Jon Lin